# Python Pycharm module path

Tags: python, pycharm

I would understand this behaviour.

In Pycharm I can successfully run (green play button) this main.py which includes src.v0.Det.py

```
src
|
+--v0
|   |
|   +--Det.py  (class det)
|      __init__.py
|
+-- main.py
    __init__.py

main.py
------------
from src.v0.Det import det
....
```

But when I run on unix using: **python main.py** I get "No module named src.v0.Det".

I can obviously remove "src" and it works but I don't want to change the file. How can I run this file like in Pycharm?

Riccardo

Answer (score -1):

> export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:<.....path.to.src.without.src....>"